# writing http post contents to file in php

Tags: php, post

I am posting a string xml data to a php page hosted in IIS. All I want is to be able to read the string data that I receive in php page and write it to a file. But am not able to achieve the same. Here is my code:-

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){ 
echo "Hello\n";
$somecontent = print_r($_POST, TRUE);

$my_file = "resp.txt";
$handle = fopen($my_file, "w") or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
fwrite($handle, $somecontent);  
    }else {
echo "Error\n";
    }
 ?>
```

But am not able to create the file or read the POST contents. I would be glad if someone would figure out how to solve this.

Comment: So what goes wrong? Which error is triggered? If none, have you tried setting error_reporting to -1?

Comment: some error must be there in ur script

Comment: @Niels- Following error I get- Cannot open file resp.txt. If i try the script outside the "POST" if condition then I am able to create the file and successfully write any data I want. But when I try to do the same from inside my POST condition, it just doesn't happen. :(

Answer (score 0):

if you know the input field name then use this.

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
 { 
 echo "Hello\n";

 $somecontent = array();
 $somecontent[] = $_POST['firstname'];
 $somecontent[] = $_POST['lastname'];
 //etc...    

 $my_file = "resp.txt";
 $handle = fopen($my_file, "wb") or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
 fwrite($handle, $somecontent);  
 fclose($handle);
 }
 else {
 echo "Error\n";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Bharat, I tried but am getting the same result i.e 'Cannot open file:  resp.txt'. If I try the same file operation from outside the POST condition or in some other php page then it's perfectly fine. Bit it just doesn't happen inside my if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){....} condition. Am thoroughly confused  :|.

Comment: @SatyaPrakashPanigrahi just try echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; this and see what you get.

Comment: I tried that Bharat, it's echoing POST. Even the line echo "Hello\n"; is executing fine. But when it comes to file operations, i don't know why it doesn't happen. I think it may be permission issue because this php page is hosted in IIS. When I post some data from my client side this php page get's hit. Don't know what exactly is the issue. I am even able to echo the data that client is posting. But when I want to write the posted data to a file, it just doesn't happen.

Comment: For the moment I am just posting a plain string like say "HelloWorld". That I am able to read in my php page by using:-
$somecontent = file_get_contents("php://input");
The above code gives me the string data that was posted. In order to use your example I would need to post in form of a query string but I am posting only a plain string. The file operations that you have suggested I am able to do in any other php script. But for this particular condition when the script is hosted in IIS and receives data posted by client, I am able to read the posted data but not able to write to file.

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
if(!empty($_POST){
  file_put_contents('resp.txt', serialize($_POST));
}
```

Comment: Thanks CodeMonkey. I will try but am not sure about this. Because now I am able to read the POST contents but am not able to do any file operation inside a PHP script that's hosted in IIS. Forget about POST, even if I wanna write a hard-coded string to a file in a PHP script (hosted in IIS) then also it doesn't work. But the same operation am able to carry out in any normal PHP script (not hosted in IIS). I don't know what could be the reason.

Comment: Sounds more like an IIS server security question than a PHP one then